# SonarQube checkstyle import error: Value 'CLASS_DEF' must be one of : LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube Version   5.1.2

Checkstyle Plugin   Version 2.3

I'm trying to import [google_checks.xml](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml).
This checkstyle config is working just fine with maven-checkstyle-plugin.
SonarQube is generating the following error

```
Value 'CLASS_DEF' must be one of : LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE.
```

The error description doesn't makes sense to me.

'CLASS_DEF' token is referenced in two places:

```
        <module name="RightCurly">
        <property name="option" value="alone"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_DO, STATIC_INIT,INSTANCE_INIT"/>
    </module>
```

and in

```
        <module name="AtclauseOrder">
        <property name="tagOrder" value="@param, @return, @throws, @deprecated"/>
        <property name="target" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF"/>
    </module>
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: per request for more info by @benzonico.

I'm not getting much help from SonarQube logging even with logging set to DEBUG.
I will re-trace my steps in trying to import google_checks.xml.

Initial import. Got log entry

```
The definition of the profile 'null' (language 'null') contains multiple occurrences of the 'checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.blocks.RightCurlyCheck' rule. The plugin which declares this profile should fix this.
```

Removing `<module name="RightCurly"/>` on line 63 and attempting re-import.
Got log entry:

```
The definition of the profile 'null' (language 'null') contains multiple occurrences of the 'checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.annotation.AnnotationLocationCheck' rule. The plugin which declares this profile should fix this.
```

There are two occurrences of `AnnotationLocation`.
Removed the first occurrence on line 166 and attempted to re-import.
This time, there is no log entry aside from

```
2015.09.08 09:29:03 DEBUG web[http] GET /profiles/create_form?language=java | time=80ms
```

..however, the Web UI displays the following message highlighted in red right under the topbar:

```
Rule template can't be activated on a Quality profile: checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.IllegalTokenTextCheck   [hide]
```

Deleting the entire `IllegalTokenText` module, and attempting re-import.
WebUI error:

```
Value ' LITERAL_FINALLY' must be one of : LITERAL_WHILE, LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FOR, INSTANCE_INIT, STATIC_INIT, LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_CASE, LITERAL_SWITCH, LITERAL_DEFAULT, ARRAY_INIT.   [hide]
```

On line 52,

```
<property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_SWITCH"/>
```

removed leading ' ' space before every token in the above line.
NOTE, ' ' is fine with other tokens (e.g. CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, etc.)
WebUI error:

```
Value 'TEXT' must be one of : text, stmt.   [hide]
```

Made 'TEXT' on line 51 lowercase..
WebUI error:

```
Value 'CLASS_DEF' must be one of : LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE.   [hide]
```

There are two lines containing 'CLASS_DEF', line 60 and line 173.
Removing the entire `RightCurly` module on line 58 which contains the first occurrence of `CLASS_DEF`
WebUI error:

```
Rule template can't be activated on a Quality profile: checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming.TypeNameCheck   [hide]
```

At this point, I'm just removing modules just to see what it takes to import anything..
Removed the entire `TypeName` module on line 91
WebUI error:

```
Rule template can't be activated on a Quality profile: checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming.MemberNameCheck   [hide]
```

Removed the entire `MemberName` module on line 91
WebUI error:

```
Rule template can't be activated on a Quality profile: checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming.LocalVariableNameCheck   [hide]
```

Removed the entire `LocalVariableName` module on line 96
WebUI error:

```
Value ' BOR' must be one of : ASSIGN, BAND, BAND_ASSIGN, BOR, BOR_ASSIGN, BSR, BSR_ASSIGN, BXOR, BXOR_ASSIGN, COLON, DIV, DIV_ASSIGN, EQUAL, GE, GT, LAND, LE, LITERAL_INSTANCEOF, LOR, LT, MINUS, MINUS_ASSIGN, MOD, MOD_ASSIGN, NOT_EQUAL, PLUS, PLUS_ASSIGN, QUESTION, SL, SL_ASSIGN, SR, SR_ASSIGN, STAR, STAR_ASSIGN.   [hide]
```

At this point, I just deleted all the remaining modules starting with the above line just to see where this ends.. 31 got imported.
But with so many rules/modules that I had to remove, the value of the import is greatly diminished.

Comment: Note that there are 3 places in which CLASS_DEF is found in the file you linked.

Comment: You are correct.  I had to remove one instance of AnnotationLocation which contained the 3rd CLASS_DEF because SonarQube import complained about duplicates.. maven-checkstyle-plugin had no problems with duplicates...

Answer (score 0):

Given what I read in [checkstyle documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/blocks/RightCurlyCheck.html) I suspect the issue is ont he Right Curly rule. This should work but it might depends on the version of checkstyle. Please precise the sonarqube checkstyle-plugin version you are using, i'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Added SonarQube Checkstyle plugin version: 2.3    Also, from talking to someone at SonarSource, I'm hearing that they are not putting much effort into maintaining these plugins.   Essentially, they are saying: we've already imported the checkstyle rules for you.   I would prefer however to be able to import my checkstyle ruleset, and then perhaps consider switching to SonarQube rules for good from using Checkstyle with Maven and Jenkins.

Comment: @cjr Given that I am a SonarSource employee and that I work on the java plugin (see my profile), I tend to share the feeling that rules of the Java Plugin are better ;) Nevertheless, we still maintain checkstyle, findbugs, and pmd plugins

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace of the error raised ? I can't figure out exactly which part of the code is generating this error.

Comment: I have updated the original post with a complete retrace of my steps.  There isn't much useful info in the SonarQube logs even at DEBUG level.   I had to go solely by the error text displayed by the WebUI right under the topbar highlighted in red.